# assembly reverse a string

Tags: assembly, tasm

The string is read until 1 is pressed, and the 1 will be on the last position of the string. I don't know why my output is off, for example the input is: asd1 and the output is: $1111. Anyway, here is my code

```
data segment
msg db 0dh,0ah,"Your string: $"
rev db 0dh,0ah,"Reverted: $"
s1 db 20 dup('$')
s2 db 20 dup('$')
data ends

code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data

start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

lea dx,msg
mov ah,09h
int 21h

lea si,s1
lea di,s2
mov bx,0
l1: mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov [si],al
inc bx
inc si
cmp al,31h
jnz l1


mov cx,bx
mov di,bx

dec1:   dec si
loop dec1

mov cx,bx
l2: mov al,[si]
mov [di],al
dec di
inc si
loop l2 

lea dx,rev
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov cx,bx
l3: mov ah,02h
mov dl,[di]
int 21h
inc di
loop l3


mov ah,4ch
int 21h


code ends
end start
```

Edit:This is what my code looks now and if I input asd1, then I get 1dserted

Comment: in `swapy:` you are storing the last character over and over again. You are not handling the state correctly, showing past the string characters and similar. Since you are using *Tasm* you also have *td* (Turbo debugger) which is quite a nice debugger.

Comment: What Margaret said, and if you expect somebody looking for your bugs in asm code, comment it. It will also help you while coding to focus first at algorithm and execution flow, then allocating registers and other resources and finally filling up the instructions, it's easier than solving all stages at the same time in head, or just trying out random instructions till the code works by accident. But avoid comments like `cmp al,31h ; compare al with 31h`, that's obvious. Write there intentions which led you to write that paragraph of code, like `; reading chars until "1" is entered`.

Comment: Besides what the others have said, the reason why you're getting a leading $ is that you post-increment `di` in `swapy` and post-decrement it in your `l4` loop (that's not a very descriptive name btw). You probably want to _pre_-decrement `di` in the second loop.

Comment: Just a suggestion to reverse a string: use PUSH and POP instructions. Push full string, then pop it, it will be reversed. Stack magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **EDIT**: After Ped7g's comment, I reworked the code. This new one doesn't use the stack to reverse the string and the string is not read as a whole string, but it is read char by char until "Enter" is pressed. Below is the new code.

```
assume cs:code, ds:data

data segment
    message db 0Dh, 0Ah, "String: $"
    reverse db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Result: $"
    string db 255 dup(0)
    result db 255 dup('$')
data ends

code segment
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Print "String: "
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, message
    int 21h

    ; Set SI where we read the string
    lea si, string

    read:
        ; Read a single character from the keyboard
        mov ah, 01h
        int 21h

        ; Save it in the memory
        mov [si], al
        inc si

        ; Check if Enter is pressed (if not, then repeat reading)
        cmp al, 0Dh
        jnz read

    ; Calculate the length of the string read
    mov ax, si
    lea bx, string
    sub ax, bx

    ; Set DI at the last char of result
    lea di, result
    add di, ax

    ; Decrement one byte to position DI on the last char
    ; of the string (the Carriage Return)
    dec di

    ; Decrement one byte because we don't want to consider
    ; the Carriage Return as a part of our reversed string
    dec di

    ; Set SI at the first char of string
    lea si, string

    reverse_string:
        ; Copy from the beginning of the initial string
        ; to the end of the reversed string
        mov al, [si]
        mov [di], al

        ; Step
        inc si
        dec di

        ; Verify if we have reached the end of the initial string
        ; (if the "current" char is Carriage Return)
        cmp byte ptr [si], 0Dh
        jnz reverse_string

    ; Print "Result: "
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, reverse
    int 21h 

    write:
        ; Write the whole reversed string on standard output
        mov ah, 09h
        lea dx, result
        int 21h

    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
code ends

end start
```

> Old answer:

You can try to use the LIFO property of stack. Below is an example of code that reverses a string using it. The algorithm puts every character from the beginning of the input string, and then pops out to the result (in the reverse order).

```
assume cs:code, ds:data

data segment

    msg db 0Dh, 0Ah, "String: $"

    rev db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Result: $"

    buffer label byte
    str_maxlen db 255
    str_length db 0
    str_string db 255 dup(0)

    result db 255 dup('$')

data ends

code segment

start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, msg
    int 21h         ; print "Your string"

    mov ah, 0Ah
    lea dx, buffer
    int 21h         ; read your string

    cmp str_length, 0
    je skip         ; check if the input is null

    mov ch, 0
    mov cl, str_length
    lea si, str_string
    put_on_stack:
        push [si]   ; copy on the stack (from string)
        inc si
        loop put_on_stack

    mov ch, 0
    mov cl, str_length
    lea di, result
    get_from_stack:
        pop [di]    ; copy back to memory (in result)
        inc di
        loop get_from_stack

    mov byte ptr [di], '$'

    skip:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, rev
    int 21h         ; print "Result: "

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, result
    int 21h         ; print the result

    mov ah,4Ch
    int 21h

code ends

end start
```

Comment: I would feel less "omg", if you would point out it's push/pop (stack) exercise (and actually very inefficient way how to do this). Or if you would read the input per char as OP does, and push each char immediately, then it would made a tiny bit more sense to abuse stack for this. BTW, push/pop will use at least 16b or 32b chunk of data, so you are doubling or quadrupling the total bytes bandwidth, watching the stack content during that reverse may be quite interesting for newcomer to asm :) .